# Recomended Nessus Windows-7 scan settings?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

In the [Nessus FAQ](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus/nessus-faq#anchor53) it says

> Microsoft Windows desktop systems have network limitations that may
>   impact the performance of Nessus. The TCP/IP stack limits the number
>   of simultaneous incomplete outbound TCP connection attempts. After the
>   limit is reached, subsequent connection attempts are put in a queue
>   and will be resolved at a fixed rate (10 per second). If too many
>   enter the queue, they may be dropped.

And the recommended settings there does not the options in Nessus 5 and I am confused about what to set in the product.

I wonder what settings you use on a Windows 7-desktop machine to make sure the scan is as reliable as possible?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use a Windows 7 desktop as the scanner or are you attempting to scan a Windows 7 machine?

Comment: With Nessus turn everything on,  always. Also expect that 95% of the findings are either false posties or totally worthless.

Comment: @ScottPack he wants to run the scan from a Win7 machine

Comment: @schroeder: I was afraid of that. Sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably referring to the maximum half-open connections limit. This shouldn't be a problem with Windows 7, as the limit was supposedly removed in Vista SP2.

You can however, check, and remove the limit if it exists.

1. Start regedit and locate

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\

1. In the right pane, locate the

> EnableConnectionRateLimiting

registry value data entry.
If “EnableConnectionRateLimiting” is not found, the half-open TCP connections limit is already removed/disabled, allowing unlimited half-open incomplete outbound connections. If the value is there, delete it - or edit it and set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Black-Box scans and using a Win7 machine as the server, you are going to run into the potential problem of half-open connections being dropped. As for the settings in the FAQ, you can find them in: `configuration > advanced settings` for the server.

You can reduce the impact of this networking limitation by supplying credentials for the target and configuring that only the local port enumerators are used (configured in the policy's `preferences > port scanner settings`). That way, you are getting a report of the open ports from the target instead of a port scan.